# ASP.NET WebAPI self-hosted app and crossdomain.xml

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How I can add crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml to my self-hosted app?

Comment: I use Mark Jones answer. It was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer by imran_ku07 http://forums.asp.net/t/1785552.aspx/1?Hosting+static+content+in+a+self+hosted+webapi all you need to do is create a route and API controller to actually serve the crossdomain.xml etc. policy files.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "CrossDomain", "crossdomain.xml",
            new { controller = "CrossDomain" });
```